# How to get the page response if i don't know the post parameters?

Tags: java, forms, http

I want to get the page response (http://202.72.14.52/p2/cci/SearchHistory.aspx) but the page only allows post method. I could't get the response because I don't know what to set in the parameter name/value pairs. I have tried to insert some data in request parameter such as TextBox1=2015&TextBox2=1&TextBox3=2016&TextBox4=17&R1=v2&DropdownList1=01

Can you make a example using this web http://requestmaker.com/?

Comment: Open your browser's `developer tools`, load the page, fill-in the parameters and submit the form. You'll see what parameters are being sent to the server.

Comment: I dont know am I correct or not. I typed R1=v2 for the checkbox. the original code is <input value="v2" name="R1" id="Radio2" type="radio" checked="checked">